# Script to send Outlook calendar by e-mail, change detail level?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a script found on https://www.crestwood.com/2018/08/17/automating-outlook-calendar-to-send-daily-agenda/. This works but I can not control the details of the calendar. Or more correctly I can't figure out how to send **Meeting subject and Location**.

Is there a way with this code? Or could I go about it in some other way?
When doing it manually in Outlook it is called "Limited details" - this is my desired outcome.

I can change the constant: olFreeBusyAndSubject between 0, 1, 2. But none of these return my desired outcome. They result in (only seeing busy/free, Only seeing subject, Full details including description of event). I do not want full details since their might be sensitive information which I do not want on my secondary e-mail.

```
' -------------------------------------------------
' Modify this \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Const myEmailAddress = "some@email.com"

Const includePrivateDetails = TRUE

Const howManyDaysToDisplay = 1

' Modify this /////////////////////////////////////

' -------------------------------------------------

Const olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule = 0

Const olFreeBusyAndSubject = 2

' Const olFullDetails = 1

Const olFolderCalendar = 9

SendCalendar myEmailAddress, Date, (Date + (howManyDaysToDisplay - 1))

Sub SendCalendar(strAdr, datBeg, datEnd)

Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkCal, olkExp, olkMsg

Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olkSes = OlkApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName

Set olkCal = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

Set olkExp = olkCal.GetCalendarExporter

With olkExp

.CalendarDetail = olFreeBusyAndSubject

.IncludePrivateDetails = includePrivateDetails

.RestrictToWorkingHours = False

.StartDate = datBeg

.EndDate = datEnd

End With

Set olkMsg = olkExp.ForwardAsICal(olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule)

With olkMsg

.To = strAdr

.Send

End With

Set olkCal = Nothing

Set olkExp = Nothing

Set olkMsg = Nothing

olkSes.Logoff

Set olkSes = Nothing

Set olkApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

As described desired outcome is to thorugh a VBA-script (or other automated way) send "Limited details"-Outlook-calendar by e-mail.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In `.CalendarDetail = olFreeBusyAndSubject` replace `olFreeBusyAndSubject` by `olFullDetails`.

To discover this I used Bing and searched for "Outlook CalendarDetail".  I find this an easy method for discovering the permitted values for a property.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you for your effort. However you are aware that in the code the olFreeBusyAndSubject is only and constant 1 or 2 as described above. Changing to olFullDetails still results in a 1 or 2. And 1 results in only Free/Busy being exported and a 2 that all details are exported. I hope I have not misunderstood you.

Comment: @Tune .CalendarDetail only has three options: (0) Free Busy Only, (1) Free Busy and Subject and (2) Full Details.  If you want a different level of detail, you will have to create the report yourself.  You could create the full report then extract the details you want to share.  Alternatively, you could generate the report yourself.  Somewhere I have a routine that demonstrates how to decode calendar entries.  If you think that would be useful, I will search for it.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Than it is a bit more complicated than I had hoped. I'd like option (1) but also the location of meeting.

Comment: Having tried your code, I cannot see the issue.  I agree "Free Busy and Subject" does not include Location while "Full Details" does.  However, my "Full Details" listing does not contain much more than "Free Busy, Subject and Location".  I am retired so my calendar does not contain everything that could be in a calendar item.  What is in your "Full Details" listing that you would want omitted?

Comment: In the Full Details it also includes all information ,text etc in the meeting details. (Describing the topic agenda etc). This could be sensitive information and not allowed to be shared to an external email account.

Comment: @Tune My brief investigation suggests option 1 should not be too difficult.  My emails have a brief entry (date & time, subject and location) for each calendar entry followed by the header "Details" followed by a detailed entry for each calendar entry which contains a repeat of the brief entry and any extra information.  Does this match your emails?  Deleting everything after the header "Details" would be easy.  Deleting the links from the brief entries to the detailed entries would be a little more difficult but not impossibly difficult.  Would this meet your requirement?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Removing everything from "Details" and down, but actually I would need to have the same change in the attached Ics-file and not only the email body. The reason for that is to easily have the info into Google calendar. Thank you again for your effort!

Comment: @Tune I had not noticed the ICS attachment since it is at the bottom of a long list of GIF attachments.

Comment: An ICS file is a text file.  Each line is of the format "XXXXXX:value" where XXXXXX identifies the type of the value.  Examples of "XXXXXX" are: "LOCATION", "DESCRIPTION" and "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html".  The values for "LOCATION" and "DESCRIPTION" are unchanged from the Outlook calendar item.  The value for "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html" seems to be an Html version of the "DESCRIPTION" split into lines.  Apparently with Outlook 2013 you would always see the "X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html" version of description but with Outlook 2016 you would see the "DESCRIPTION" version.

Comment: This change from Outlook 2013 to Outlook 2016 was being treated as a bug in 2016 so it might have been fixed.  Deleting both descriptions does not look too difficult.  Would this give you what you need?